# Vtiger 7.5.0 tab icon

Tags: php, header, vtiger

I want to change the tab icon for my vtiger

I have tried almost everything i could come up with eg: renaming the new icon to favicon, editing header.tpl to the new icon but nothing seems to work. would appreciate any help with this.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
layouts/v7/skins/images/favicon.ico
```

with the new icon.

Don't forget to empty your browser's cache (usually ctrl+f5).